# PyDev 7.3.0 warns uselessly about iterable unpacking with Python 3.7

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

*Stop editing just to gain few points of reputations and not helping, thanks*

First of all, it does not bother the compilation of my code. The command `(base) user@machine:~$ python script.py` works perfectly and gives what I expect. 
What is bothering is during the edition of the code in Eclipse. While the following line is acceptable and compiled well with Python 3.7 `a,b,c = *func_returns_2_things(),func_returns_1_thing()`.
 What Eclipse warns : `Encountered "*" at line X, column Y. Was expecting one of: "("..., "{"... #and so on` 
Of course, I tried this `[*func_returns_2_things(),func_returns_1_thing()]` but it still warns an error: `Expected:]`.
 Besides I shouldn't not say "warns" because warning are mentioned with a yellow triangle, and here this is clearly a red circle with red cross in (if you know what I mean).

What can I do to stop this useless warning in my Eclipse edition ?

*Notes: `def func_returns_2_things(): return 1,2` ; `def func_returns_1_thing(): return 4`*

---

**Versions** 
*Eclipse IDE for Java Developers* 
Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200

*PyDev for Eclipse*
Version: 7.3.0.201908161924
Build id:org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group
Provider: Fabio Zadrozny

*Pydev Mylyn Integration*
Version: 0.6.0
Build id:org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature.feature.group
Provider: Fabio Zadrozny

Comment: PyDev and Eclipse both have newer versions. You should try updating to them first.

Comment: @nitind I clicked "Help" in menu, then clicked "check for updates" and accepted the updates. It updated and there is still this problem occurring.

Comment: @nitind  now that's updated it don't work anymore: `No editor descriptor for id org.python.pydev.editor.PythonEditor` while PyDev is installed...

Comment: Modern Eclipse and PyDev need Java 11.

Comment: @nitind I would prefer to know that before. That's super easy to do on Ubuntu, haha.

Comment: @nitind update to Java 11 in order to use the last version of Pydev keeps the error: `Encountered "*"`.

Comment: Sounds like a big to report to them, then.

Comment: @nitind Seriously ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is probably that your project is configured to validate the syntax for a different version of Python.

i.e.: In the project properties, PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar you probably have an older version of Python selected (either in `Grammar version` or `Additional syntax validation`).

See: https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for more details.

Comment: You were right. First, I checked in the menu `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Pydev` -> `Interpreters`  -> `Python interpreters`. By default it was selected a version in the root `/usr/bin/python` that I do not use and changed to the desired one `/path/anaconda/bin/python3.7`. Second, as you told, with a Right Click on the project, then clicking `Properties` - > `Pydev interpreter/grammar` I can change as I want which version to use: the default selected previously in First or another. Thank you!